# Objective-C | NSBezierPath draw and color on action

Tags: objective-c, drawrect, nsbezierpath, nstrackingarea

I have a custom view class with a tracking area. I want that, when the mouse enters the tracking area, a bezier is drawn with a color, and when the mouse exits the area the bezier disappear. In order to make it disappear I read that the only way is to change its color with the window background color.

I managed to add the tracking area, but I don't know how to draw the bezier. If I put the code in

```
-(void)drawRect:(NSRect)dirtyRect
```

it's drawn when the app launches, but I don't want so. I tried with this:

```cs
@implementation MSBezier

- (void) viewWillMoveToWindow:(NSWindow *)newWindow {
    // Setup a new tracking area when the view is added to the window.
    NSTrackingArea* trackingArea = [[NSTrackingArea alloc] initWithRect:NSMakeRect(164.5, 17.5, 270, 65) options: (NSTrackingMouseEnteredAndExited | NSTrackingActiveAlways) owner:self userInfo:nil];
    [self addTrackingArea:trackingArea];
}

- (void) mouseEntered:(NSEvent*)theEvent {
    NSLog(@"Entered");
    color = [NSColor colorWithCalibratedRed: 0.044 green: 0.813 blue: 0.044 alpha: 0.441];
    CGFloat rectangleCornerRadius = 31;
    NSRect rectangleRect = NSMakeRect(164.5, 17.5, 270, 65);
    NSRect rectangleInnerRect = NSInsetRect(rectangleRect, rectangleCornerRadius, rectangleCornerRadius);
    rectanglePath = NSBezierPath.bezierPath;
    [rectanglePath appendBezierPathWithArcWithCenter: NSMakePoint(NSMinX(rectangleInnerRect), NSMinY(rectangleInnerRect)) radius: rectangleCornerRadius startAngle: 180 endAngle: 270];
    [rectanglePath appendBezierPathWithArcWithCenter: NSMakePoint(NSMaxX(rectangleInnerRect), NSMinY(rectangleInnerRect)) radius: rectangleCornerRadius startAngle: 270 endAngle: 360];
    [rectanglePath appendBezierPathWithArcWithCenter: NSMakePoint(NSMaxX(rectangleInnerRect), NSMaxY(rectangleInnerRect)) radius: rectangleCornerRadius startAngle: 0 endAngle: 90];
    [rectanglePath lineToPoint: NSMakePoint(NSMinX(rectangleRect), NSMaxY(rectangleRect))];
    [rectanglePath closePath];
    [color setStroke];
    [rectanglePath setLineWidth: 3];
    [rectanglePath stroke];

}

- (void) mouseExited:(NSEvent*)theEvent {
    NSLog(@"Exited");
    color = [NSColor colorWithCalibratedRed: 0.949 green: 0.949 blue: 0.949 alpha: 1];
    CGFloat rectangleCornerRadius = 31;
    NSRect rectangleRect = NSMakeRect(164.5, 17.5, 270, 65);
    NSRect rectangleInnerRect = NSInsetRect(rectangleRect, rectangleCornerRadius, rectangleCornerRadius);
    rectanglePath = NSBezierPath.bezierPath;
    [rectanglePath appendBezierPathWithArcWithCenter: NSMakePoint(NSMinX(rectangleInnerRect), NSMinY(rectangleInnerRect)) radius: rectangleCornerRadius startAngle: 180 endAngle: 270];
    [rectanglePath appendBezierPathWithArcWithCenter: NSMakePoint(NSMaxX(rectangleInnerRect), NSMinY(rectangleInnerRect)) radius: rectangleCornerRadius startAngle: 270 endAngle: 360];
    [rectanglePath appendBezierPathWithArcWithCenter: NSMakePoint(NSMaxX(rectangleInnerRect), NSMaxY(rectangleInnerRect)) radius: rectangleCornerRadius startAngle: 0 endAngle: 90];
    [rectanglePath lineToPoint: NSMakePoint(NSMinX(rectangleRect), NSMaxY(rectangleRect))];
    [rectanglePath closePath];
    [color setStroke];
    [rectanglePath setLineWidth: 3];
    [rectanglePath stroke];
}

@end
```

But the bezier isn't drawn.

Thanks for your help!

**EDIT**
@uchuugaka

This is the code so far, which doesn't seem to do anything:

```
@implementation MSBezier

bool shouldDrawMyPath = YES;
NSBezierPath *rectanglePath;

- (void)viewWillDraw {

    if (shouldDrawMyPath == YES) {
        NSColor *color = [NSColor colorWithCalibratedRed: 0.044 green: 0.813 blue: 0.044 alpha: 0.441];
        CGFloat rectangleCornerRadius = 31;
        NSRect rectangleRect = NSMakeRect(164.5, 17.5, 270, 65);
        NSRect rectangleInnerRect = NSInsetRect(rectangleRect, rectangleCornerRadius, rectangleCornerRadius);
        rectanglePath = NSBezierPath.bezierPath;
        [rectanglePath appendBezierPathWithArcWithCenter: NSMakePoint(NSMinX(rectangleInnerRect), NSMinY(rectangleInnerRect)) radius: rectangleCornerRadius startAngle: 180 endAngle: 270];
        [rectanglePath appendBezierPathWithArcWithCenter: NSMakePoint(NSMaxX(rectangleInnerRect), NSMinY(rectangleInnerRect)) radius: rectangleCornerRadius startAngle: 270 endAngle: 360];
        [rectanglePath appendBezierPathWithArcWithCenter: NSMakePoint(NSMaxX(rectangleInnerRect), NSMaxY(rectangleInnerRect)) radius: rectangleCornerRadius startAngle: 0 endAngle: 90];
        [rectanglePath lineToPoint: NSMakePoint(NSMinX(rectangleRect), NSMaxY(rectangleRect))];
        [rectanglePath closePath];
        [color setStroke];
        [rectanglePath setLineWidth: 3];
    } else {
        rectanglePath = nil;
    }

}

- (void)drawRect:(NSRect)dirtyRect {
    [[NSColor clearColor] set];
    NSRectFill(self.bounds);

    if (shouldDrawMyPath == YES) {
        [rectanglePath stroke];
    }
}

- (void) viewWillMoveToWindow:(NSWindow *)newWindow {
    NSTrackingArea* trackingArea = [[NSTrackingArea alloc] initWithRect:NSMakeRect(164.5, 17.5, 270, 65) options: (NSTrackingMouseEnteredAndExited | NSTrackingActiveAlways) owner:self userInfo:nil];
    [self addTrackingArea:trackingArea];
}

- (void) mouseEntered:(NSEvent*)theEvent {
    NSLog(@"Entered");
    shouldDrawMyPath = YES;
    [self setNeedsDisplay:YES];
}

- (void) mouseExited:(NSEvent*)theEvent {
    NSLog(@"Exited");
    shouldDrawMyPath = NO;
    [self setNeedsDisplay:YES];
}

@end
```

I'm sure I'm doing something wrong.

**EDIT 2**

I just needed to set the color in `drawRect:`. So:

```
-(void)drawRect:(NSRect)dirtyRect {
    if (shouldDrawMyPath == YES) {
        NSColor *color = [NSColor colorWithCalibratedRed: 0.044 green: 0.813 blue: 0.044 alpha: 0.441];
        [color setStroke];
        [rectanglePath stroke];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So this is pretty simple. 
You need to rearrange things. 
First create a BOOL property like shouldDrawMyPath
this should default to NO.

Next, in mouseEntered:
Set that to YES
Call self setNeedsDisplay:YES

Next, mouseExited:
Set that to NO
Call self setNeedsDisplay:YES

Add an NSBezierPath property. 
In viewWillDraw
If shouldDrawMyPath == YES
Set up your bezier path. 
Else set it to nil
( I am assuming your view might resize any time)
If your view never resizes, you can create the path once.

In drawRect
First clear the board, especially if your view could resize. 
[[NSColor clearColor] set];
NSRectFill(self.bounds);

Draw anything always there if anything.

If shouldDrawMyPath == YES
Fill and/or stroke your path. 
Else 
Do any other drawing without the path.

As long as you set up your tracking area correctly this should get you going.

Depending on specifics there are always optimizations.

Never draw outside of drawRect unless you know what you're doing.

Keep your drawRect code simple.

Only draw what you need to when you need to. (You're not there yet, but there are a lot of optimizations that can be done to invalidate and only draw particular rects)

Comment: Thank you first! I did all what you suggested me, but in the view doesn't appear any bezier, maybe should I post the code? Perhaps I misunderstood something...

Comment: I edited the post with the new code, if you want to take a look.

Comment: I played around with the code and figured out how to make it work. Thanks!

Comment: I figured you would get it. You had enough of the right ideas in the wrong places.